# How to use a class constant inside a double quoted string?

Tags: php, string

In the following code, how to use `myClass::myConstant` inside a double quoted string?

```
class myClass {
    const myConstant = 'constant value' ;
}

//WORKS
echo myClass::myConstant ;

//NONE OF THESE WORK
echo "{myClass::myConstant}" ;
echo "{$myClass::myConstant}" ;
echo "${myClass::myConstant}" ;
echo "{${myClass::myConstant}}" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

However, you *can*:

```
$foo = myClass::myConstant;
echo "something $foo something else";

echo "something " . myClass::myConstant . " something else";

printf('something %s something else', myClass::myConstant);
```

Comment: You are answering the opposite question, i.e. how to AVOID using a class constant...

Comment: @Seth I have amended my post to directly answer the question as-asked.

Comment: Fair enough. Does this apply to a class static variable as well? i.e. `echo "${myClass::$staticVar}"` is not possible either?

Comment: The syntax is opened by the literal token `{$`, so if it doesn't start with that it won't work.